# Inserting images (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

does anyone know why my code does not display the image.
I get the error "tcl error: Couldn't recognize image file"

```
    logo = PhotoImage(file="knights.jpg")
    label_Image = Label(login, image=logo)
    label_Image.grid(column = 4, rowspan = 4)
```

Comment: [The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a jpg, convert it to a gif, otherwise you have to import modules and it makes things too complicated

Comment: also make sure the image is in the same file location as the program file

Comment: Too complicated? It literally takes two-three more lines which is importing PIL, opening the jpg file and keeping a reference.

Comment: for someone who is just starting out at python like myself it may be, its easier

Comment: @TomLowbridge: making sure the image is the same file location as the program file is bad advice. Since it's not full qualified, it must be in the current working directory, which may or may not be the same location as the program file.

Comment: @BryanOakley can you elaborate, i don't understand what you mean by full qualified? sorry i'm new

Comment: @TomLowbridge: "fully qualified" means the filename is complete (eg: /foo/bar/knights.jpg")

Comment: Modules are really easy to import.